# ASP.NET targetFramework

Tags: asp.net, deployment, target-framework

**Problem:**
[image]

I did the following steps to deploy my ASP.Net WebApp and solve the problems:

1. I installed the right NetFramework by following command to IIS

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe"
>   -iru

2. [image]
3. [image]

Nothing works.